# How to make HTTPS post request in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, post, https, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to make a HTTPS post request.

```
String url = "https://myhttpsurl.com"
URL myurl = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
String query = "confirmation_number=" + URLEncoder.encode(confNumber, "UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-length",String.valueOf(query.length()));
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);

DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
output.writeBytes(query);

output.close();
System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con.getResponseCode());
```

I'm getting the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)

Please suggest what is causing the error

Comment: He hasn't asked how to ignore anything, and providing that as a duplicate merely exposes him to a security vulnerability. Very poor choice of duplicate, guys.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not able to verify the validity of the SSL certificate on the https server.  It is either self-signed or signed by a certificate authority not known to the Java runtime.

Your options are to manually trust the certificate by adding it to the truststore (cacerts), or to have your certificate signed.  I don't recommend disabling the SSL certificate validation completely, as you might open yourself to unexpected consequences.

Comment: Here is a good example of how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/2464657

Comment: Looks good, but as listed, they'd have to do it again when the JRE is replaced.  I always recommend to make your own cacerts file, copied from the JRE, then import and trust to it.  Then set the system property "javax.net.ssl.trustStore".  Six to one, half dozen to the other... either way is a bit of work to have the setting not lost.

Comment: Agreed I just think the direct import into the JRE is a bit simpler for beginners. But as you said, both are valid.